# Create Teams-room with DynamicMembership using PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I want to create a new team in Microsoft Teams with dynamic membership using powershell using the modules MicrosoftTeams and AzureADPreview

I can create a new team using the command

```
New-Team -DisplayName "NewTeam" -Description "New Team" -MailNickName "NewTeam" -Visibility "Private"
```

When I try to set the group type to Dynamic Memberehip with the command,

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id "xxx" -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -MembershipRule "user.mailNickname -eq ""yyy"""
```

I get the following error message:

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup : Error occurred while executing SetMSGroup
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more properties contains invalid values.
InnerError:
  RequestId: e82c8ab7-c0a1-4631-b983-fc5cb2b0e860
  DateTimeStamp: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 12:13:37 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureADMSGroup -ID "db9e3933-1883-4d3a-88fe-f95d29b5d8c6" -Securi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADMSGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.SetMSGroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had excatly the same issue, and a hard time to figure this one out as MS Docs are just a piece of crap. So, the culprit is acutally not the membership rule, this one is fine, though everything points into it's direction. But in reality, its all about the "GroupType" which seem to be wrong in the MS Docs.

So this is the correct command to convert an Unified Static Group to a Dynamic one:

```
Set-AzureAdMsGroup -ID xxxx -GroupTypes @("DynamicMembership", "Unified") -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -MembershipRule "(user.mailNickname -eq ""yyyy"")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct ansver! For some reason you have to include both DynamicMembership AND Unified as GroupTypes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following cmdlet to to set the group property and see it works

```
Set-AzureADMSGroup -Id "xxx" -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.mailNickname -eq ""yyy"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: Hi Manu. Unfortunately, the parentheses doesn't help.

Comment: Can you check, if you can do it from Azure portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-change-type

Comment: In the portal i can set the membership to Dynamic User, set a membership rule, and save without error. But when i refresh the group, the membership type is reverted to Assigned. Maybe it is a permission issue? I'll check with the system admins

Comment: It seems like there was just a delay, the group is now set to DynamicMembership after i edited in the portal. I still have to find a way to set it using PowerShell.